# Android Studio 3.1.2 - Turn VCS OFF

Tags: android, git, android-studio, version-control

I recently did an Update of my Android Studio to version 3.1.2.
Apparently somewhere along the line an Update caused my VCS to turn ON.
I don't need this and it is causing me headaches when I try to build my Signed APK.

I have followed the advice on a variety of Stackoverflow postings, but none of them have worked.  Some of them appeared to work temporarily, but when I did a restart of AS and opened up a previous Project, I find GIT set ON again.

When I go to **File → Settings → Version Control** I can highlight my Directory and then Edit it to change it from GIT to None.   I then did an APPLY.  And it seems to work, but when I go back in it has set itself back to GIT.

I even found the VCS.XML file in my .ideas directory and edited it to remove GIT, only to have it reverts itself to 'on' when restarting Android Studio.

How can I, in version 3.1.2, turn OFF the VCS for good?

Comment: Which versioning tool are you using? I don't understand the relation between having VCS activated and the ability to build an APK

Comment: "Versioning Tool" ??  I don't understand the term.    When I try to build and some of my java files are appearing in RED (which they never did before), I get an error.  Apparently I did not have nor need VCS before so how do I turn it off now?

Comment: Have look at [that](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-About-Version-Control) to know what is a versioning tool (or Version control system (VCS)). Basically it allows you to easily go back to a previous version of your code. It's a very good practice to use one (most popular are Git and Mercurial).
But the versioning tool has nothing to do with the ability of building the app. You have probably another issue. Please post your error logs

Comment: And the colour on your files is normal if VCS is activated. Like that you can know if the file has been added to it, modified, is a new added file,...

Comment: Yes, the color of the files is normal if VCS is activated, but it was never activated in previous SDK versions.   I do my own Version Control with ZIP/RAR files and do not want/need the SDK to get in my way.   So how do I disable it totally?

Comment: Remove the vcs.xml file in the `.idea` folder of your application and the `.git` folder. But I recommend you to learn how to use a proper VCS as it's very powerful, very convenient, and not really complicated to use. ZIP/RAR is not a VCS, and is actually a very bad practice

Comment: Thank you.  That appears to have FINALLY disabled VCS in the SDK and restored my project to how it worked before my SDK update FORCED VCS enabled.  I needn't get in a discussion about the pros and cons of VCS, but after 35+ years of successfully developing complex applications in a variety of languages and implementation arenas, I have NEVER found VCS to be a benefit - and most especially not when FORCED upon me.

Comment: I'm glad it has solved your issue. But you should have a look at VCS and how they work. You could be very surprised as it generally saves you a lot of time and you can't really do without it if you are working on a team project.

Comment: I've posted an answer so you can approve it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your application folder, remove:

- the `vcs.xml` file in the `.idea` folder
- the `.git` folder